# Import CSV file onto JTable

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, csv, user-interface

Trying to import a csv file onto my Jtable without using a CSV reader. Any Advise on how to approach this?

```
table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
            },
            new String[] {
                "ID", "Country", "Status", "Person"
            }
        ));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    }
```

Comment: See this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543540/importing-a-csv-file-into-a-java-swing-table

Comment: Want to try do it without a CSV reader or any packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\usr\\test.csv")));
            List<String[]> elements = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
                String[] splitted = line.split(";");
                elements.add(splitted);
            }
            br.close();

            JTable table = new JTable();
            String[] columNames = new String[] {
                    "ID", "Country", "Status", "Person"
                };

            Object[][] content = new Object[elements.size()][4];

            for(int i=0; i<elements.size(); i++) {
                content[i][0] = elements.get(i)[0];
                content[i][1] = elements.get(i)[1];
                content[i][2] = elements.get(i)[2];
                content[i][3] = elements.get(i)[3];
            }

            table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(content,columNames));

            System.out.println(table.getModel().getValueAt(1, 1));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: getting an error on this line  List<String[]> elements = new ArrayList<String[]>();

Comment: And could you post the error? What java version are you using?

Comment: Managed to fix it :), but for some reason getting a file error java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: My test csv file was created under C:\\user\\test.csv. You must change path or create a file under this locations.

Comment: Yep I did it I got this error not sure what it means java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ross\Desktop. (Access is denied)

Comment: It means you do not have administrator privleges and you can't read from this location. Create new folder at C:\ and put the file there and the try again.

Comment: any ideas why im getting this error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1  I put it in same project my file and imported it as "test.csv" but I get that error

Comment: Because I want to get all values not just (1,1)

Comment: Do you have any emoty values? Like let say 1;;FIXED;Person

Comment: yep I have one empty value in my CSV file so under a heading there is no value for that person

Comment: I changed this String[] splitted = line.split(";"); to this String[] splitted = line.split(","); so it could read the file. So this line  System.out.println(table.getModel().getValueAt(1, 1)); prints out 9 to the console and the table is empty and thats all it prints

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124098/discussion-between-freefall-and-ross-c).